# When is -av NOT the appropriate option for rsync?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I somehow never really get around to learning the use of `rsync` – whenever I need to do some copying/syncing, I think about it, then decide *nah, I'll just use `scp`*.

Which is probably not a good idea though, in particular `rsync` is clearly superior for *updating* a backup. If only I knew how to use it... whenever I've determined that I should really use `rsync` for a particular sync job, I then read up lots of man / internet advice, get utterly confused by the pleathora of options, try around several of them before actually getting the result I want, and quickly forget how I did it again.

So, in order to get *used* to `rsync` at last, I'm looking for simple rules of thumb. In particular, it seems the “standard” use usually seems to involve the `-a` flag, which the manual says means “archive” and lists some things it does, but leaves me confounded as to why I'd actually want them and in particular if I might have reason *not* to want some of them.

Thus my question: if I make it a habit of copying files by default with `rsync -av`, what situations should I look out for when this is **not** a good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### When should you *not* use `rsync -av` ?

**tl;dr**: When you don't want the behaviour provided by `-a` or by `-v`, don't use those options!

In addition, [Gordon Davisson](https://superuser.com/users/7778/gordon-davisson) points out another exception:

> if you aren't running it as root (on the destination system), or the user and group IDs don't match between source or target systems, you may not want to (/be able to) preserve users, groups, and device and special files.

And [xenoid](https://superuser.com/users/670091/xenoid) makes a point abut *adding to `-av`*:

> There are also case where you can add to `-av`, `-av --delete` will replace the additive backup by a mirroring (use with care (ie, try first with `-n|--dry-run`) otherwise you backup can be deleted if you match the wrong directories.

### `-v` (increase verbosity)

Easy one first: `-v`. From the [rsync manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

> ```
>  -v, --verbose               increase verbosity
> ```

This one is pretty straightforward to see the effect of. If you're not concerned with transfer info, omit it.

### `-a` (archive mode)

Right, `archive` mode. For this, it's worth having a read of [What is archive mode in rsync?](https://serverfault.com/questions/141773/what-is-archive-mode-in-rsync) over on Server Fault.

[Andrew's good answer](https://serverfault.com/a/141778) lists the modes it includes:

> -r, --recursive             recurse into directories
>
> -l, --links                 copy symlinks as symlinks
>
> -p, --perms                 preserve permissions
>
> -t, --times                 preserve modification times
>
> -g, --group                 preserve group
>
> -o, --owner                 preserve owner (super-user only)
>
> -D                          same as --devices --specials
>
> --devices               preserve device files (super-user only)
>
> --specials              preserve special files

and *excludes*:

> -H, --hard-links            preserve hard links
>
> -A, --acls                  preserve ACLs (implies -p)
>
> -X, --xattrs                preserve extended attributes

As he notes, it's *perfect for backups*; because if you are backing up you want to make an exact copy of the data you are backing up, along with information about the files.

#### Why wouldn't you want to use `-a`, then?

Generally speaking, if you are in a situation where you don't want `-a`, you'll know. Maybe:

- you want to copy files from a directory, but not its subdirectories (so no `-r`)
- you want to copy symlinks are actual files =, because your destination filesystem doesn't support symlinks (no `-l`)
- you aren't concerned about permissions (no `-p`)
- you want to update modification times (no `-t`)

The last one is probably the most obvious use case.